# How to transfer and install an older version of Whatsapp from one phone onto a another phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, apk

My whatsapp auto-updated to the new version yesterday which has the blue ticks. Since I am not a big fan of this version, I was wondering if I can install an older version of this app on my S4. One of my old phones(S3) has the previous version of whatsapp. Is there a way I can transfer this version to my S4?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am sure you can find the .apk file of older version of Whatsapp available over third party sites but better to watch out what you are getting from them as I don't trust with their apks other than playstore.

Comment: You can use Whatsapp plus, I think they have a solution to the blue ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways->

1) If you are rooted-> Go to data/app and there you can find whatsapp apk file. Just transfer it normally using bluetooth or whatever.

2) If you are unrooted-> Create a new folder `Apps` inside your internal sdcard .Download [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en). Open it and enter the command `cp /data/app/*.apk /sdcard/Apps`. This will transfer all the installed packages in APK form including whatsapp apk. It may take sometime depending on number of apps you have installed. You could also just minimize terminal and wait.

3) As others suggested, you can also download from third party site on web.

A note though, as far as I can remember, whatsapp will persuade you to install new versions and wont let you use older versions. But again, I could be wrong so feel free to give it a try.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Open WhatsApp and go to `Settings` > `Account` > `Privacy` > Un-tick Read receipts.

[image: Screenshot of WhatsApp settings]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts.  OP is asking a way to transfer an app from one phone to another. This does not answer the question.

Comment: He just wanted to get rid of blue ticks.. That's exactly why he wanted older version of whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of apps like Software data cable to get this work done.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.damiapp.softdatacable&hl=en

Using this app you would be able to transfer everything from your S3.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an app like link2SD that will allow you to directly shear the app with another device via Bluetooth or upload the .apk to a service like Google Drive or DropBox:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD

Answer (score 0):

You can download the apk from third party websites easily, though they may not be trustworthy. Also someday you have to install the latest version back again as older whatsapp versions expire out after a certain period of time.